# Python: List index out of range on Bubble Sort

Tags: python, list, sorting, indexing

I'm making Bubble Sort in Python, but for a reason I don't know of yet, a "List index out of range" error happens when and only when I run the code, with line 6 (if array[n] > array[n+1]:) causing the error.

Here's the code:

````
    n = 1
    b = len(array)
    while b > 1:
        while n < b:
            if array[n] > array[n+1]:
                array[n], array[n+1] = array[n+1], array[n]
            n += 1
        b -= 1
        n = 1
    return print(array)
array = [5,4,3,2,1]
bubblesort(array)```
````

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question!

Comment: Python arrays starts with `0`, not `1`.  Also, what do you suppose happens for `n+1` when `n` is the last index? Mind you `len(array)` will always be an index out of range as arrays start with `0`.

Comment: Consider the case where `n=4` (i.e. b=5).

Answer (score 0):

Working code with minimum changes:

```
def bubblesort(array):
    n = 0                # Updated
    b = len(array) - 1   # Updated
    while b > 0:         # Updated
        while n < b:
            if array[n] > array[n+1]:
                array[n], array[n+1] = array[n+1], array[n]
            n += 1
        b -= 1
        n = 0            # Updated
    print(array)         # Updated

array = [5,4,3,2,1]
bubblesort(array)
```